# My Windows 10 computer shuts off while playing Scrap Mechanic

Tags: gaming, repair, help-files

I have a Win10 computer with 2 repairs in it. After them the computer was running fine. But in 30th October while playing a game the computer shutted down. I checked for any updates. Then i updated my computer, but it didn't give anything at all. No BSOD, dump didn't save, can't get anything to debug. Nothing shown that computer will shut down, no error. I run these 2 commands:

```
sfc /scannow
DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
```

Then i run the game again, played some time and it shut down again. I also reinstall the game, but nothing. Please help :(

Answer (score 1):

I think that your problem is with the computer warming too much when playing
this game. This can be either the CPU or the graphics card (GPU).

You may install some monitoring product, such as the free
[SpeedFan](http://www.almico.com/speedfan.php),
which can be configured to display the current temperatures in the taskbar,
for easy monitoring.

If warming is the problem, you may :

- Verify that the game uses the video card and not the CPU
- Clean up all airways
- If a laptop, place it at an angle, so the air can pass below it,
  or buy a cooling pad
- Renew the thermal paste below the CPU (better done by a professional)
- Replace the CPU air-fan by a better one (also better done by a professional)

Comment: Warming isnt the problem. HWMonitor PRO says CPU heat is 47.3 celcius while playing. GPU uses 1.15 V while playing and 0.95 while idle. Thermal paste is very new. Fan radiator is newly clean. CPU fan is at 1698 RPM. None of warming is NOT a problem.

Comment: If the problem is not hardware, then it might be the game itself. In any case, check the Event Viewer for useful errors or warnings.

Answer (score 0):

try closing all running programms
or make graphics low
if it will not work go to files and set some useless models to 0 it will make your cpu cooler it will not use all 100% of pc when is does pc just turns off
try to optimize it maybe you have limit placed like:
if cpu usage is 60% your pc turns off set it to 100% and thats it